# xss bypass regex with slash character

Tags: xss, owasp, wapt

I would like to understand why the `/` character is useful to bypass some regex xss filters.
For example, let's take one of the most common attack vectors `<svg/onload=alert(1)>`. Can anyone explain the reason why using a slash instead of space character works? From the resources I'm studying, it says that the vector can bypass this regex `(on\w+\s*=)` but I can't understand why. This may look a trivial question but I've been searching around and could not find anything bound to the root cause why this works.

Answer (score 0):

It works when RegEx is like `<\w+ (on\w+\s*=.*)`. We can see that it will prevent XSS when there is a space before `on` keyword so using `/` will bypass this RegEx check. Some RegEx considers `/` as a part of tag name. Well, it totally depends on RegEx but we know that normally `on` event starts after space so mostly developers assume a space before `on` event and make RegEx accordingly which can be bypassed using `/`.

Comment: ok, it's clear. But why the browser parses `/` between the tag name and handler as a space character? I mean why `<svg/onload=alert(1)>` renders as `<svg onload=alert(1)>` in a html page?